# Android app cannot be put to Amazon store?

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility

I am trying to put my app to the amazon store but I get the following error:

*YOUR_APP does not install on Kindle Fire. Please consult the Kindle Fire FAQ for a listing of compatible permissions called in your Android Manifest file, as these may be causing problems with your app’s installation on Kindle Fire. If your app currently lists a permission that is not critical to the functionality or user experience of the application, we recommend that you remove it from your manifest file.*

And here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >            
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>    

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity> 

    <activity android:name=".SubjectsActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".secondActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".thirdActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Select">
    </activity> 
</application>
```

Any help is welcome and appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kindle Fire uses SDK version 10 ([Kindle Fire FAQ](https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#KindleFire)).  You're probably getting an error since you require a minimum version of 11.

Comment: I'll come back with some feedback. +1